# Should I call .close() on both SQLiteDatabase and SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqlite

```
SQLiteOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new (ctx, nameofdb);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpener.getWritableDatabase();
```

Do I have to call `.close()` on both of these, or just one of them is enough? If yes, then which one?

```
SQLiteDatabase
SQLiteOpenHelper
```

The problem I am having is that I do not see one particular row in DDMS view in Eclipse, but when I use the Cursor to get it, it shows that I do have that entry. So I am wondering it might be caused by not closing the database properly? Anybody who can help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the docs for [SQLiteOpenHelper.close()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#close%28%29)...

> public synchronized void **close ()**
>
> Close any open database object.

It doesn't close the `SQLiteOpenHelper`, it closes the database.

Further to this, if you get your code right you can avoid dealing directly with the database object directly altogether.

For example, if you have a query you use regularly to get a cursor for an adapter to populate a view, create a method in your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and put the query into that.

In other words, don't get a reference to the actual database in your main code just get the `SQLiteOpenHelper` to do everything for you.

Comment: What's about the [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)? I thought that `SQLiteOpenHelper` class is using only [to help] to open (to create\update) a database.

Comment: @LeonidSemyonov : It could be argued that by simply extending any class and adding functionality (new methods or implementing interfaces) adds extra responsibilities anyway...but doing that is a fundamental principle of OOD/OOP. It's not uncommon in Android to create a generic DB 'helper' class which itself maintains a `SQLiteOpenHelper`. My point is in certain cases, `SQLiteOpenHelper` can be extended to provide *ALL* of the DB 'helper' methods rather than having a separate DB 'helper' POJO.

Comment: @Squonk does `close any open database object` imply that it'll close all the SqliteDatabase instances open in the app(assuming that there are multiple open) or does it only close the ones which are tied to the current SqliteOpenHelper object?

Comment: @zack : A `SQLiteOpenHelper` only ever handles a single instance of a database at any one time. I suppose the use of the word *'any'* is slightly ambiguous. The `close()` method simply checks the instance variable referencing the database is `!=null` and checks that the database is actually open - if both conditions are met, the database is closed and the instance variable is nullified. Any other `SQLiteOpenHelper` and their associated databases are left untouched.